# CKEditor buttons are disabled on modal window when using Safari/Chrome works as expected on FF and IE10

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, config, toolbar, contenteditable

I am trying to integrate CKEditor within my MVC4 application so that users are able to edit an email template with their content. Within the NewCampaign page I have successfully tested that the CKEditor toolbar is displayed and working as shown in the image below:

[image: in page]

On the NewCampaign page I want to display the template to the user in the form of a modal window and have used jQuery reveal-modal to display this. When I set `contenteditable` field to true and click the CKEditor toolbar is shown but all of the buttons are disabled as shown in the image below:

[image: in modal]

I cannot understand why the buttons are disabled and would greatly appreciate if anyone who has encountered a similar problem could direct me to a solution as I have tried numerous things with this all day.

Three buttons are working on the toolbar in the modal:

- Find
- SpellCheck
- About

Comment: Question has been rewritten and updated with images

Comment: Can you show your config and the code used to replace the textarea with CKE? That simply looks like a classic disabled editor, nothing special about it. Do you disable it programmatically at any point?

Comment: My config is the basic config: CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
 // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
 // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.toolbar = 'Basic';
};  and I have not disabled it programmatically

Comment: Haven't you forgotten about `contenteditable="true"` attribute?

Comment: no this is added to the attributes. The bar is appearing as expected just that the buttons are not enabled when in the modal window

Comment: I have just noticed that this is occurring on GoogleChrome and Safari but the buttons are working OK in IE10 and Firefox. What could be causing this? It seem related to the Layout engine

Comment: Without a working example we won't be able to guess what's wrong.

Comment: Theres nothing wrong its a bug with the tool I have given up using the plugin and instead have created my own

Comment: @Jay: what browser were you using when this problem was experienced? I think it may be browser-dependent.

Comment: @Reinmar: do you think my explanation below indicates a bug, or would you expect this behaviour in CKEditor?

Comment: @halfer: While working on CKEditor I saw some problems with hidden elements. Some browsers return incorrect values for computed styles, the selection does not work, retrieving some attributes or element's properties doesn't work, etc. So CKEditor may not work correctly in such case. You can report a bug on http://dev.ckeditor.com and we'll verify it, but we need details to be able to reproduce it. As for modals - some libraries (like jQ UI) are known for messing up focus behaviour (and perhaps more), so CKEditor cannot work with them. People find hacks though.

Comment: @Reinmar: thanks. If I get a chance I will provide a reproducible bug report, though using the `visibility` style seemed to fix it for now.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that there is a browser-dependent issue here in version 4.3 (rev d2184ac), which exhibits at least in Safari/Mac but not Firefox/Mac.

I have a `div` with `contenteditable="true"` set via `setProperty`, but it is hidden at the time with `display: none;` and remains hidden when the editor instance is created. Revealing it later has the above effect: the toolbar is disabled, and `contenteditable` has been reset to `false`.

It looks like using `visibility` rather than `display` will fix it in my case, at least in Safari/Mac.

Comment: I decided to design my own editor as I found this pretty terrible